How to align in itextsharp signature box
I have a signature area that surrounds the words "Nhận xét" and "Người xác nhận".
enter image description here
I keep the size of the signature area the same and align the corner of the signature so that the signature is in the corner of "Người xác nhận" (Bottom Right Corner)
